# MySQL - two dependent weighted averages in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

**This question extends a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319429). I want to add a weighted average total in addition to some individual weighted averages.**

I have a MySQL table which looks like this:

```
id  load_transit    load_standby    hours_transit   hours_standby
1   40              20              8               4
2   30              15              10              10
3   50              10              3               9
```

I need to do the following calculations:

(intermediate calculations)

```
hours_transit_total = 8+10+3 = 21
hours_standby_total = 4+10+9 = 23
hours_total = 21+23 = 44
```

**(new extra desired result)**

```
load_transit_weighted_mean = 40*(8/21) + 30*(10/21) + 50*(3/21) = 36.667
load_standby_weighted_mean = 20*(4/23) + 15*(10/23) + 10*(9/23) = 13.913
load_total_weighted_mean = 36.667*(21/44)+13.913*(23/44) = 24.772
```

Is it possible to do this in a single query? What would the best design be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By extension of my answer to your previous question, this is just as simple:

```
SELECT sum(hours_transit * load_transit) / sum(hours_transit),
       sum(hours_standby * load_standby) / sum(hours_standby),
       (sum(hours_transit * load_transit + hours_standby * load_standby)) / sum(hours_transit + hours_standby)
FROM table1
```

Here is the [corresponding sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a30a1/6).

Comment: Thanks. Is there no way to 'cache'/subquery the result of each SUM(hours_x * load_x) statement, so they don't have to be queried twice? I'm wondering about performance (my real-life table will have many more columns and rows).

Comment: I don't know whether the queries would be run twice - try explaining it and see what happens.